# My Spigot Minecraft plugin doesn't say "yum" when I eat something

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft

I'm working on a Spigot plugin right now. but I'm having some problems with it. I'm having issues with the listeners. I've watched tutorials but it didn't work. When I eat something in-game it doesn't say "Yum!" It doesn't do anything. I tried to fix it but I can't. I don't think it's because I put it in the same package.

Listeners.java :

```
package adawda.awdwa;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerItemConsumeEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerMoveEvent;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Listeners extends JavaPlugin implements Listener
{
    public Listeners(Awdwa plugin)
    {

    }
    public void onEnable()
    {
        Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerItemConsume(PlayerItemConsumeEvent event)
    {
        event.getPlayer().sendMessage("Yum!");
    }
}
```

---

Awdwa.java ( Main ) :

```
package adawda.awdwa;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.bukkit.Server;
import org.bukkit.World;
import org.bukkit.entity.EntityType;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.Cancellable;
import org.bukkit.event.HandlerList;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerJoinEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerBedEnterEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerItemConsumeEvent;
import org.bukkit.plugin.PluginManager;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;

import java.util.Arrays;

public final class Awdwa extends JavaPlugin implements CommandExecutor {
    public Location homeLoc;
    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        // Plugin startup logic
        PluginManager pm = getServer().getPluginManager();
        Listeners listener = new Listeners(this);
        pm.registerEvents(listener,this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
        // Plugin shutdown logic
    }
    public void onPlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent event)
    {
        Bukkit.broadcastMessage("Naber, " + event.getPlayer().getName()+"!");
    }
    public void onPlayerBedEnter(PlayerBedEnterEvent event)
    {
        Bukkit.broadcastMessage("birisi uyuyor.. daha doğrusu çalışıyor.");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
        String cmdName = cmd.getName().toLowerCase();
        Player p = (Player) sender;
        if (cmdName.equals("example")) {
            sender.sendMessage("UwU it works!");
            return true;
        } else if(cmdName.equals("sethome")) {
            homeLoc = p.getLocation();
            return true;
        } else if(cmdName.equals("home")) {
            p.teleport(homeLoc);
            return  true;
        } else if(cmdName.equals("kedi")) {
            World w = getServer().getWorld("world");
            int i = 0;
            w.spawnEntity(p.getLocation(), EntityType.CAT);
            w.spawnEntity(p.getLocation(), EntityType.CAT);
            w.spawnEntity(p.getLocation(), EntityType.CAT);
            w.spawnEntity(p.getLocation(), EntityType.CAT);
            w.spawnEntity(p.getLocation(), EntityType.CAT);
            w.spawnEntity(p.getLocation(), EntityType.CAT);
            w.spawnEntity(p.getLocation(), EntityType.CAT);
            w.spawnEntity(p.getLocation(), EntityType.CAT);
            w.spawnEntity(p.getLocation(), EntityType.CAT);
            w.spawnEntity(p.getLocation(), EntityType.CAT);
            w.spawnEntity(p.getLocation(), EntityType.CAT);
            w.spawnEntity(p.getLocation(), EntityType.CAT);
            w.spawnEntity(p.getLocation(), EntityType.CAT);
            w.spawnEntity(p.getLocation(), EntityType.CAT);
            w.spawnEntity(p.getLocation(), EntityType.CAT);
            w.spawnEntity(p.getLocation(), EntityType.CAT);
            w.spawnEntity(p.getLocation(), EntityType.CAT);
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Please remove the `extends JavaPlugin` in your **Listeners.class**. This will only be needed inside the **Main.class**. Your **Listeners.class** should only implement Listener by default. You should then also remove the constructor and the onEnable() method inside your Listeners class as they are not needed.

You should then change your way of registering events inside your **Main.class**. You should register events like this:

```
pm.registerEvents(new Listeners(), this);
```

(Create a new Listeners Object inside the registerEvents() method)